# is SOQL capable of self joins mysql style?

Tags: salesforce, apex, self-join, soql

Is it possible to do a self join with table aliasing? Lets's say I'm a book shop and I want to get all customers that purchased a book last week AND this week. In MySQL this would look somehow like this:

```
    SELECT Account.id from Opportunity o1, Opportunity o2    
    WHERE o1.closeDate = Last_WEEK AND o2.closeDate = This_WEEK 
    AND  o1.Account = o2.Account
```

What would be the equivalent in MySQL? It keeps puzzling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare one Opportunity Account Id with another in SOQL (`o1.Account = o2.Account`). If you try you will get the message:

> Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

If instead you rework the SOQL to use a sub query you will get a different error.

```
SELECT AccountId from Opportunity o1  
where o1.closeDate = LAST_WEEK 
  AND o1.Account in 
  (SELECT AccountId from Opportunity o2 WHERE o2.closeDate = THIS_WEEK)
```

Gives:

> The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type.

You will need to either:

1. perform two queries to get the required data. You could feed the resulting Account Ids of the first query into the second query as a where clause filter.
2. retrieve the Account Ids with either close date in one SOQL query and then build up the required sets with code.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.